Azure B2C Angular MSAL not saving refreshed token
I have a SPA Angular App with Azure B2C authentication.
The app has a refresh_token expired, and the call to
/b2c_1a_signup_signin/oauth2/v2.0/token

with grant_type: refresh_token returns error
"AADB2C90080: The provided grant has expired. Please re-authenticate and try again. Current time: 1714587838, Grant issued time: 1713896015, Grant expiration time: 1713982415\r\nCorrelation ID: 0d7b6059-183c-41fa-b679-feeca8bb8aea\r\nTimestamp: 2024-05-01 18:23:58Z\r\n"

But the next call I see is
grant_type: authorization_code

Which is successful. As part of the response, I saw a new refresh_token returned. That token is valid.
The issue is, that new refresh token is not saved, so when I make another API call (or page refresh) the old token is used, and app has to make another call to refresh token.
That behavior seems wrong to me and I can't figure out if I have to manually refresh the token in local storage? I expect azure/msal-browser to take care of it.


"@angular/core": "^17.3.6"
"@azure/msal-angular": "^3.0.16"
"@azure/msal-browser": "^3.13.0",

